# Start task using calendar object where just the second is set

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

Using below code, I'm attempting to start a thread when the second part of the time reaches 0 - ie when the next minute starts.

```
public class Sched {    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Calendar calStart = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
        calStart.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);   
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Sched().new RC(), calStart.getTime().getTime(), 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private class RC implements Runnable {
        public void run() { /* some impl */}    
    }
}
```

But the thread is not starting. It appears I am not setting the start time correctly. I could get this to run by setting the `initialDelay` param to `0`, but why is setting using the calendar object not working?

FYI, hardcoding `initialDelay` to zero works (tested on JDK8):

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Sched().new RC(), 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're using a `Calendar` object (actually, I don't know why *anyone* would use one, but that's another story).

Try just using integer arithmetic on the current time to calculate the number of seconds till the next minute:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Sched().new RC(), 
    60 - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 % 60, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Timezone is irrelevant to this code, since the seconds part of a date is the same no matter which timezone you're in.

Answer (score 1):

As a reminder, the signature for scheduleAtFixedRate is:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

initialDelay and period are both in TimeUnit units.

You're setting initialDelay to the UNIX timestamp of the current time in a specified time zone with **just** its seconds field set to 0.  For reference, at the exact moment I checked this, the UNIX timestamp was 1432907829.

Meaning that you just told your timer to wait over 1 billion, 432 million seconds before it starts and then run every 3 seconds.